# ASP.NET Core MVC How token passing with url is secured

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have looking into code of a web application where token is generated and injected into url instead of auth cookie for each request token is passed with url to accessed secured action. The web application is using token instead of auth cookie. Token life is one day.

This is a sample url

```
http://localhost:48000/ACX/Default/Login?token=8kzRLdW8lQVIS0MrtlqdZJbmz9p22l33u1wspGOmLgCgEy2MG5XZ0JG1ovVZGiNX7KpAfBVn3
```

of that web application where token is passing through url.

This code is generating the token which would valid up to 24 hours:

```
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)  
{  
    if (user == null)  
    {  
        return BadRequest("Invalid request");  
    }  
      
    if (user.UserName == "johncitizen" && user.Password == "abc@123")  
    {  
        var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("KeyForSignInSecret@1234"));  
        var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);  

        var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(  
            issuer: "http://localhost:2000",  
            audience: "http://localhost:2000",  
            claims: new List<Claim>(),  
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440), // valid till 24 hours
            signingCredentials: signinCredentials  
        );  

        var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);  
        return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return Unauthorized();  
    }  
}
```

My question is: when token is passed through the URL, then any other person can get the URL and impersonate the user. I guess passing token through URL is not secure.

What can we do as a result token would be secure passing through URL? I want to change flow bit in such a way that if another user copy and paste the same URL, then he will not be able to access protected resource. So how to achieve and secure long life token?

Please guide me with approach in details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `IDataProtectionProvider` protect your data.

Configure in your `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
```

Or you can also specify algorithms (using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection`) used for `encryption` and `validation`, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
       .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptionSettings()
       {
           EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_GCM,
           ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
       });
```

Then inject `IDataProtectionProvider` into your controller, Create your own key And create Create `encryption` and `decryption` methods:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //Inject IDataProtectionProvider into your controller
        private readonly IDataProtectionProvider _dataProtectionProvider;

        //create your own key
        private const string Key = "my-very-long-key-of-no-exact-size";

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
        }

 

        public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)  
        {  
            //...............

            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);

            var keytoken = Encrypt(tokenString); 

 
            return Ok(new { Token = keytoken });  
            
            //...............
       }        

        //encryption methods
        public string Encrypt(string input)
        {
            var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(Key);
            return protector.Protect(input);
        }

        //decryption methods
        public string Decrypt(string output)
        {
            var protector = _dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(Key);
            return protector.Unprotect(output);
        }
}
```

Now, Token has been encrypted.

[image]

Even if someone else gets your toke, Because they don't have the key, So they can't decrypt the token.

Comment: whatever encryption i used but when token passed with url then how it would be secure? another guy just copy that url and send request to my site. how my site would be able to understand that request is coming from valid user? please explain. thanks

Comment: Hi, The project can't understand Wheather the token is coming from valid user, As long as the token is still valid, your program will think it comes from a valid user. So your aim needs to be how to prevent another guy get your token instand of encrypting the token.